# sql query multiple inner joins. "Copying To Tmp Table" takes too long

Tags: mysql

This is my table"user":

id(auto_increment, primary_key), userid(unique), key(unique), value

first index: id

second index: userid + key

example rows:

1, 1, "car", "red fast expensive"

2, 1, "house", "beautiful with garden two floors"

3, 1, "smartphone", "with camera and  mp3"

4, 2, "car", "red fast expensive"

5, 2, "house", "beautiful with garden two floors"

6, 2, "smartphone", "with camera and  mp3"

7, 3, "car", "red fast expensive"

8, 3, "house", "beautiful with garden two floors"

9, 3, "smartphone", "with camera and  mp3"

**Now i want to find all users that have all of this key-value pairs above.**

This is my query:

```
SELECT kv1.val AS val1, kv2.val AS val2, kv3.val AS val3 
FROM user AS kv1 
INNER JOIN user AS kv2 ON kv2.userid = user.userid 
INNER JOIN user AS kv3 ON kv3.userid = user.userid 
WHERE (
      ( kv1.key = 'car' && kv1.val LIKE '%expensive%') && 
      ( kv2.key = 'house' kv2.val LIKE '%beautiful%') && 
      ( kv3.key = 'smartphone' && kv3.val LIKE '%camera%')
      )
```

That works fine. 
But my problem is: A test query with 10 million rows tooks 4.7 seconds. 
phpmysql says that 98,91% of the time is for "Copying To Tmp Table"

Is there an other way to make it faster ?

Comment: why do you have two joins instead of only one to the same table?

Comment: You said `userid` is a unique index, but you have `1` in your first three rows and `2` in your next three rows, etc. Also, `key` doesn't seem to be a unique index either. Multiple rows have the same value there too.

Comment: @Dave This is an Index over two columns key + userid. One user can only have one same key

Answer (score 0):

i found out that "ORDER BY" makes it extrem slow...